# Which nut is this?

Tags: identification

I found this nut in the woods in Massachusetts. I had thought that it were a chestnut, but that does not seem to be the case. Thanks!

[image: Top View]

[image: Bottom View]

[image: Ruler View]

Comment: Please pry the hull apart to get to the actual nut, then post a picture of the nut. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I want to plant this, would prying apart the hull damage it? Thanks.

Comment: How big is it? It's not obvious from the pictures.

Comment: The outer shell is going to split into four eventually. If you push something blunt like a credit card into the cracks and twist a bit, you won't damage anything.

Comment: I have added a picture with a ruler and a black beech seed. It weights 17 grams.

Comment: It's almost certainly a hickory nut.

Comment: Yes that it is! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a hickory nut. Hickory nuts have 4 quadrants, like your nut. Try looking up pictures of hickory nut and see what you think (I've never seen such a nut in real life).

Comment: I think that you are right. The leave matches what I saw around there as well. Thank you!

Comment: It's always easiest to identify a nut by the actual nut and not by the hull. I'm curious as to what the actual nut looks like.